# GCM not working with multi-user

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, multi-user

Is there a way I can get GCM notification working with multi-user?
I have a few users in my device and one of the applications in User1 uses GCM, but when switching to User2 - User1 will not get any GCM notification since it is not the current user. is there a way to allow it? for example if the application running in User1 was a system app or asked for some permission similar to the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS permission...
I would like to avoid a solution where I have to install the application in User2 and register to GCM in User2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think that's possible, all process are killed for the inactive user. Your assumption is correct the second user will have to register to GCM as well.